# how to parse a $resource object in angularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-resource, angularjs-http

I have one annoying problem here that I need help with.
I have a controller that fetches stock data from yahoo stocks.  The controller stores the data in $scope.stocks, in my view I can display the data with an ng-repeat so everything works great.  The problem comes when I try to extract some data from each element of the data... it says the object is undefined.
Below is my controller that does the fetching.

```
    app.controller('controller2', ['$scope','$resource', function($scope, $resource){
    var URL='http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json';
    $scope.stockAPI=$resource(URL, {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},{get:{method:'JSONP'}});
    $scope.stocks=$scope.stockAPI.get({});
    console.log($scope.stocks);
    var temp=$scope.stocks.list.resources;  // this returns an error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'resources' of undefined)
    console.log(temp);

}]);
```

My view that uses this controller is shown below (also this view shows the data that I want)

```
    <body ng-app="weatherApp" class="container">
    <div ng-controller="controller2" ng-model="buffer">
        <h1>This is the index page where the application is mounted</h1>
        <ul ng-repeat="stock in stocks.list.resources">
            <li>{{stock.resource.fields.name}}  {{stock.resource.fields.price}} {{buffer.push(stock.resource.fields.name)}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

The json data that I get back from the controller looks like below, and the view can render it just fine, but I can not make a new list that contain only three fields out of the multitude of fields contained within each element of the object... Please help this has been frustrating me for two days.

$promise: d

$resolved: true

```
list: Object

 meta: Object

  resources: Array[173]

      [0 … 99]

      [100 … 172]

      length: 173

      __proto__: Array[0]

  __proto__: Object
```

**proto**: e

Answer (score 2):

You should pass a function and then do set `$scope.stocks` inside that function

```
$scope.stockAPI.get({}, function(data){
   $scope.stocks = data;
});
```

Otherwise you could use `$promise` and then do update `$scope.stocks` inside your `.then` function.

```
$scope.stockAPI.get().$promise.then(function(data){
   $scope.stocks = data;
});
```

Comment: @BuyaNami does it helped you..?

Comment: Pankaj thanks for your response.  I've tried both methods, using the second method -the $scope.stocks in defined within the callback function but not defined in the controller's scope, so it returns undefined when I console.log($scope.stocks) outside of the .then() part.
In the first method I get a $scope.stocks object but I can not parse through it- console.log($scope.stocks.list) returns undefined.

Comment: @BuyaNami you can not have async call response outside its function..we are setting a `$scope.stocks` because we are dealing with async call

Comment: e {$promise: d, $resolved: false}   // this is from outside of the callback function app.js:58
// this one is from inside the callback function, this value is not available outside of the callback function  
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object,  Object…]

Comment: @BuyaNami use `debugger` to `debug` javascript or use `console.log(variableName)` & then press f12 to see the value in console

Comment: Yes, I have been looking at the console prompt to compare variables in different lexical locations.
When I look at (console.log($scope.stocks) inside the call back it has the values I need only.
When I look at the (console.log($scope.stocks)) outside of the callback function it contains additional parameters and I can not referense any of the fields.

Comment: @BuyaNami you much place that inside the callback function of async , did you saw my first comment

Comment: This is my entire app.js

{var app=angular.module('weatherApp', ['ngResource']);
app.service('agrigator', function(){
 var self=this;}
app.controller('controller2', ['$scope','$resource','agrigator', function($scope, $resource, agrigator){
 var URL='http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote?format=json';
 $scope.stockAPI=$resource(URL, {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},{get:{method:'JSONP'}});

 $scope.stocks=$scope.stockAPI.get({},function(data){
     $scope.stocks= data.list.resources;
  });
 console.log($scope.stocks); 
}]);}

Comment: `var app=angular.module('weatherApp', ['ngResource']); app.service('agrigator', function(){ var self=this;} app.controller('controller2', ['$scope','$resource','agrigator', function($scope, $resource, agrigator){ var URL='finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/…;; $scope.stockAPI=$resource(URL, {callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},{get:{method:'JSONP'}}); $scope.stockAPI.get({},function(data){ $scope.stocks= data.list.resources; });}]);` update to this

Comment: Parker I updated it with your suggestion.
it gave me undefined when I console.log($scope.stocks) outside of the get's callback function.

Comment: @BuyaNami bro why you are repeating things again and again..I told you several times that don't put `console.log($scope.stocks)` it would be undefined always because that is going to set inside async callback..Is your value populated on UI?

Comment: it did not resolve, but I think I'm going to try using services to do the fetching part and return a promise back to me in the controller.  Next I'll use .then to do filtering on the json response from $http call- I'm afraid I'll call the service every time I want to look at the data instead of looking at a locally stored copy of it which is easier/more efficient, I'll worry about efficiency after I get to work correctly.
Thanks for you help Pankaj.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved.
This is how to go about it in case you have a similar problem.
first of all realize http calls are done asynchronously, second try to use a service to handle asynchronous tasks (or local data warehousing in general).
so lets get to the details;

```
var app=angular.module('app',[]);
app.service("DataService", function($http, $q){
var defered=$q.defer();  // this is not for the HTTP delay... instead it is for populating our local Names and Lengths variables --defined below
var buffer=[];  // I'm not sure if I need this anymore but It hold a promise as well
var Names=[];  // these are the variables I'm interested in using, which I first need to populate them from an http call that I'll call later
var Lengths=[];  // also this is a local variable that I want ( just for kicks)

var url='http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php'; // ofcourse our remote server API that responds with a jason full of data 
// this function is called from inside our fetchdata method defined below this method, this function processes the data (from the http promise once successfull)--- it just parses through the json objects and isolates/groups similar data --- all the names go into a name array and the length of each name goes into a different array ( I want to make a D3 chart from it in the end) 
var fixup= function(data){
    var records=data.records;  // records now contains an array of objects with few fields each

    records.forEach(function(record){
      console.log(record.Name+"  ----  "+record.Name.length); // taking a look/peak at the individual records fields 
      Names.push(record.Name); // store each record's name value in our local Names array
      Lengths.push(record.Name.length); // do something similar for the length of each name
    })
    defered.resolve(Names);// this is the main thing here-- you will send our local Names array once everything works out- i.e the data has arrived from the server and the loop is finished running processing the fetched data... when you return the promise (as we will see later) it will contain whatever we put the resolve as an argument so here it is Names array, it could be whatever you want
} // so that is it for fixdup function
// next is our fetching method
var fetchData=function(){
    $http({             // this is an asynch call, it moves on to the next method once the call is made-- so you have no data still. 
        method: 'GET',
        url: url
    }).success(function(data){ // this is the next big deal here the promise (internally used by the http service) is processed here- if successful this function handles the response if not the next method handles the errors
        buffer=fixup(data);// give the data to our fixup function we saw above
    }).error(function(err, status){
        console.log(err);
    })
}// so anyone that looks at buffer will not see anything unless the .then method of this promise object is invoked

console.log('fetching data away we goooo....'); // lets us know where we are at the console logs
fetchData(); // does the fetching business which calls the fixup method which calls defered.resolve() method.
return defered.promise; // this will wait untill we're done with defered.resolve(Names) call... this returns a promise that we will have our names array sometime later

});
// here we are going to use our dataservice service we defined above... remember it will only five us something once the resolve(names) finishes running
app.controller("controller1",['$scope', 'DataService', function($scope,  DataService){
//$scope.myData=[];
$scope.names=[];  // these guys are clue less about where their data is coming from, so they are just chilling here in the scope unaware of what's about to happen
$scope.lengths=[]
DataService   // kapow!! we call our get-us-some-data service happily named DataService ofcourse
.then(function(names){ // so this function is fired up once we have names parameter available--- this is sent from the last call in the DataService service (return defered.promise) which as we discussed will only run when the resolve(Names) is done running  ... I know it sounds confusing but it will take you few tries to get a hung of it--- took me two long days to rap my mind about this asynch thing --- I'm too synch to a fault haha OK moving on
    console.log('back from DataService sendit service method'); // inspect our efforts here... first let us know where we are when we get an output on the console
    $scope.names=names; //  here is the magic... after all those promises and and back and forth method calling we end up with out own local scope names array exactly like we wanted and we can give this data to a D3 directive and everyone is happy
    console.log(names);
    })
.then(function(names){ // we can chain promises and do other things here, I'm populating another local scope variable from the same promise returned... so we will not need to call fetch data again we have our own clean data here in our controller... also I would like to make it better by putting this part in the service inside a wrapper that looks if the local data is empty call fetchdata and follow the same steps else return the populated local data (local to the service) and many controller can now have access to the same data as it should be
    $scope.names.forEach(function(name){$scope.lengths.push(name.length);})
    console.log($scope.lengths);
    });


}]);
// I hope this helpes people new to the whole promises and asynch methods in general
```

Please let me know if I made a comprehension error anywhere since I'm still learning this asynch approach, I will greatly appreciate it.

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular JS library-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- D3.js library -->
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" class="container">
    <div ng-controller="controller1">
        <div ng-repeat="n in names">
            {{n}}-------{{lengths[$index]}}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

this is the index.html I used for looking at our scope
it works like magic... If anyone is interested when I combine it with D3 let me know I will include it here.
later guys.